# need ignore basic http auth

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have trouble with getting page source.

```
    require 'mechanize'

    agent = Mechanize.new        
    page = agent.get("https://#{ip}/")
```

end have error:

```
    /home/lord/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:682:in `response_authenticate': 401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized for https://82.144.208.6/cgi-bin/welcome.cgi -- no credentials found, provide some with #add_auth -- available realms: r722 (Mechanize::UnauthorizedError)
from /home/lord/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:288:in `fetch'
from /home/lord/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize.rb:407:in `get'
from /home/lord/ruby/ruby_backup/backup-done.ru:35:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

how can I ignore http auth, and get source? thx

Comment: You are required to provide credentials otherwise you won't be able to access the page.

Comment: yes, but if I use curl - have resp with error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception contains a page accessor. The documentation describes it: http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/ResponseCodeError.html

Try:

```
begin
  page = agent.get ...
rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
  page = e.page
end
```

Comment: thx. change ResponseCodeError to HTTPUnauthorized and job done